# How to Import a golang package which has git submodule depedency in it

Tags: go, gitlab, git-submodules, go-modules

I want to create a repo containing json files let us say mapping of countries to country ids, and import this repo in a golang package using git submodule for example called as transformer which reads the json for countries and creates a map and uses that for some operations.

sample structure

```
repoA: 
-- country.json (mapping of country text to country id)

repoB: (golang package)
-- json (repoA added using git submodule)
-- transformer.go (logic to read json/country.json file and create lookup tables ).

repoC: (golang service)
-- main.go (uses repoB's transformer functionality).
```

When we import the created package (transformer or **repoB**), its dependency which is on **repoA** containing our country json file to read, is not imported in **repoC** and hence **repoB package fails to read json**.

tried to fetch submodules,
tried to create build and run but json file was not being read.

expecting that the submodule dependency is present in the imported package.

Comment: Why not importing both repoB and repoA in repoC, and pass the json as an argument to repoB functionality? something like `repoB.Transformer(repoA.Country.JSON)`

Comment: @ChenA. the repoA is not a go package it is just a normal repo containing bunch of json files. This repoA cannot be a go package as it can be imported in a node project to get the same mappings.
How can we import such repos if we go by your approach ?

Comment: You can use a git library to checkout this repo in repoC. then pass the file to the function provided from repoB

Comment: You cannot do what you want. Go's package and module system doesn't allow to do this. While a Go module _can_ be fetched via git it still is something different and knows nothing about git submodules. You must redesign.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to add a generator in repoB to generate a go source file that holds the content of the json files. For example,

```golang
// jsondata.go
// Code generated by tool; DO NOT EDIT.

package jsondata

const file1 = `{"field":"value".....`
const file2 = `{"field":"value".....`
```

If the files are too large, you can zip them. Remember to put this file into a separate package so when this package is not imported, it won't affect the size of the final program.

This is how the go tool itself is designed to embed tzdata in a program. See this proposal for more information: [time: add time/tzdata package and timetzdata tag to embed tzdata in program](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/38017)